# Django ManyToManyField to Permission

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with `ManyToManyField` to `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission`

The problem is that when I open to edit my model record in admin, the number of database requests are 241

```
class RoleManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(RoleManager, self).get_query_set().select_related('organization')

class Role(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length = 80)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, blank = True)

    objects = RoleManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{name} in {organization}'.format(name = self.name, organization = self.organization.name)
```

235 of SELECTs are:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 8
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 8
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 8
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 68
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 69
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 69
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 69
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 9
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 9
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 9
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 10
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 10
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 10
SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 17
```

May be I have to use Manager to fix this?

I looked https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py

and saw that Permission is using some PermissionManager, but not sure what exactly is happening, and how to make it in my manager

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the [`prefetch_related` `QuerySet` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), that's its intended purpose!

This should reduce your query overhead to just one query for all the related objects.

Comment: Sure, but how exactly. I tried some combinations with parameters, but can't make it

Comment: @ju. Did you try `return super(RoleManager, self).get_query_set().select_related('organization').prefetch_related('permissions__content_type')`?

Comment: Yes :( But I can tell you today for sure

Comment: @ju. I take it from your output that you are using Django Debug Toolbar, care to look at where those requests are being executed exactly?

Comment: I tried it again, it doesn't help at all. They are executed from django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html line 19 {{ field.field }} Take a look at last link that I put in question. I think the GroupManager is the answer how to do it, but can't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Debug Toolbar can make this requests, if you are using it.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this from doing so?